# Spring Integration: Pass Entire List of object from router to service at one time

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, splitter

I have the following splitter in my code
For e.g

```
public class CurrencySplitter {

public Collection<CurrencyDomain> split(String[] currency) {
    List<CurrencyDomain> list = new ArrayList<CurrencyDomain>();

    list.add(new CurrencyA(12, "A"));
    list.add(new CurrencyA(13, "A"));
    list.add(new CurrencyB(12, "B"));
    list.add(new CurrencyC(12, "C"));

    return list;
   }
  }
```

Splitter Configuration:

```
<si:payload-type-router input-channel="currencyCreateSplitChannel">
    <si:mapping type="com.vce.domain.CurrencyA" channel="createCurrencyAChannel" />
    <si:mapping type="com.vce.domain.CurrencyB" channel="createCurrencyBChannel" />
    <si:mapping type="com.vce.domain.CurrencyC" channel="createCurrencyCChannel" />
</si:payload-type-router>

<si:channel id="createCurrencyAChannel">
</si:channel>
<si:service-activator input-channel="createCurrencyAChannel"
    method="createCurrencyA" output-channel="currencySplitResponseChannel"
    ref="currencyService">
</si:service-activator>
```

...

Service Class :

```
public class CurrencyService extends BaseService {

public CurrencyDomain createCurrencyA(List<CurrencyA> currA) {

    System.out.println(currA.size());
    return new CurrencyDao.save(currA);
}

public CurrencyDomain createCurrencyB(CurrencyB currB) {

    System.out.println("B");
    return new CurrencyDomain("B");
}

public CurrencyDomain createCurrencyC(CurrencyC currB) {
    System.out.println("C");
    return new CurrencyDomain("C");
   }

 }
```

The problem is I need entire CurrencyAList at one shot so that i save all the data at one time. But now createCurrenyA is method is called two times with seperate dao calls.

Need help on how can i get all the currentA objects as a list and saved at once

Comment: where and how it is getting called 2 times?

Comment: @Pranalee, that true, because `<splitter>` produces messages for each collection entry and it doesn't know anything about `A` business key. That's why `CurrencyService#createCurrencyA` is invoked twise for the two `A` messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `<aggregator>` for that case before `<si:service-activator>` invocation:

splitter -> payload-type-router -> aggregator for `CurrencyA` objects

```
<si:chain input-channel="createCurrencyAChannel" 
                output-channel="currencySplitResponseChannel">
   <si:aggregator correlation-strategy-expression="1" 
      group-timeout="100" 
      expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
      release-strategy-expression="true"/>
   <si:service-activator method="createCurrencyA" ref="currencyService"/>
</si:chain>
```

Since all your payloads for that `createCurrencyAChannel` are `CurrencyA` you can just use that simple `<aggregator>` configuration. It means:

- form only single group for all incomming messages, becuase the `correlationKey` is `1`
- since we may don't know the count of incomming messages we just release the group by `timeout`
- as far as we always should release our `release-strategy` is always `true`
- To allow form a group for any new messages after the prevous release we should remove those `completed` group, hence `xpire-groups-upon-completion="true"`